# Load AngularJS Website in Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, webview

I'm trying to load a website built in AngularJS into a WebView. It's not working.

```
webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() );
webView.loadUrl("http://www.websitedomain.com");
```

Getting error:

```
 I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(13212)] "Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module explore due to:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'someVariable' of null
at https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/js/app.js:129:45
at Object.invoke (https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13277:17)
at runInvokeQueue (https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13183:35)
at https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13192:11
at forEach (https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:9163:20)
 at loadModules (https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13173:5)
 at createInjector (https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:13099:11)
 at doBootstrap (https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10457:20)
  at bootstrap (https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10478:12)
  at angularInit (https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js:10372:5)
   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/modulerr?p0=explore&p1=TypeError%3A%20Cannot%20read%20property%20'isLogin'%20of%20null%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Fjs%2Fapp.js%3A129%3A45%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Object.invoke%20(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13277%3A17)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20runInvokeQueue%20(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13183%3A35)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13192%3A11%0A%20%20%20%20at%20forEach%20(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A9163%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20loadModules%20(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13173%3A5)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20createInjector%20(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A13099%3A11)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20doBootstrap%20(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A10457%3A20)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20bootstrap%20(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A10478%3A12)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20angularInit%20(https%3A%2F%2Fwww.websitedomain.com%2Fapp%2Fwww%2Flib%2Fionic%2Fjs%2Fionic.bundle.js%3A10372%3A5)", source: https://www.websitedomain.com/app/www/lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js (13212)
```

Comment: Does it work in browser ?

Comment: Make sure to test your website in a regular browser. The error you're getting seem to suggest that something is wrong with your web app rather than the WebView. You need to look up why you get an error in your app.js at row 129.

Comment: @Hrym: the website is working fine at chrome in mobile, but its not even displaying anything in webview.